# can't load css file with django

Tags: python, css, django, web-applications

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" type="text/css" />

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
```

Above are my settings and html settings. Although I can get /static/css/main.css in my HTML file, but I can't load 127.0.0.1/static/css/main.css.   What can I do to fix this?

Comment: try `{{STATIC_URL}}css/main.css` instead.

Comment: No, I can get "static/css/main.css"  in my HTML file, but if I load the address directly from the browser, it simply doesn't work...

Comment: Can you paste the `structure ` of your `project` please?

Comment: Did you forget the port? `127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.css`

Answer (score 3):

To load static successfully you should consider:

- `STATICFILES_DIRS` should contain list of folders to your static
- `STATIC_ROOT` shouldn't be empty. Set it i.e. `collected_static`.
- In case you launch your django site in `DEBUG=True` django will use static directly from STATICFILES_DIRS and in case you launched django site in `DEBUG=False` you should make `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

> Add  line in **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

> run command:- **python manage.py collectstatic**

static folder generated

[image]

> **FOR LOAD CSS FILES**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'media/style.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

ON your STATICFILES_DIR = (
)

change it to a list:

> ```
> STATICFILES_DIR = [
> # place STATIC_DIR in here ending in a ,
> ]
> ```